# How to fetch or store data into a database on a LAMP server from devices over the internet?

Tags: python, mysql, database, lamp, mysql-python

I have a python code which needs to retrieve and store data to/from a database on a LAMP server. The LAMP server and the device running the python code are never on the same internet network. The devices running the python code can be either a Linux, Windows or a MAC system. Any idea how could I implement this?

Comment: Set the LAMP server to a static IP internally. Port forward the LAMP server externally. Connect the python apps to the external IP of your network.

Answer (score -1):

> are never on the same internet network.

Let me clear the question, the problem is `are never on the same internet network.` firstly you need to fix the network issue, add router between the two sides which you want to communicate with. No relations with `Python` or `LAMP`.

1. let me assume your DB is mysql, if you can make you can access that DB from outside servers, you can just talk with that DB directly from another servers.
2. but for another solution, I recommend you to use API which would cover all request above the DB, then you can talk with that API to handle the data.

Comment: "never on the same network" - example: server is at home and you try to connect to it from a coffee shop

Comment: I don't think so, if that server couldn't make an IP out side the internet, maybe you need like https://ngrok.com/ to expose a port from your home PC.

Comment: You don't need a proxy service like ngrok if you have direct access to the router.

Comment: @cricket_007 just said what i had meant. The database server is at home and all other devices trying to access the database, aren't.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes you are right, if we can have fixed IP we can easily forward that to external. But I don't recommend that, I am not sure whether you have used the proxy service like ngrok, it should be the easiest and safest way to communicate between two network environment.